# Is there any way to install and run an UWP app on windows10 in S mode?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10s, uwp

After enable S mode on windows 10. I try to setup and run an app which isn't on MS Store. .exe app is blocked. So I try using UWP app package to setup. And now i have installed an UWP app. But it is still be blocked by windows defender. CAN AN UWP APP RUN ON WINDOWS 10 S MODE?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jafff.png)

Comment: I thought he whole point of the S mode was that it *only* ran apps from the Windows Store.

Comment: disable S mode again